How to avoid references to each other in Object?
I designed the following class for the game in production.
    public class Character
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<SustainedAction> ActionsInParticiption = new();

        public void PlayTalk(Character target) { new Talk(this, target); }
        public void PlayLecture(Character target) { new Lecture(this, target); }

        public void ShowActionList()
        {
            foreach(var action in ActionsInParticiption) 
                Debug.Log(action.Name);
        }

        public void EndAction(SustainedAction action) { action.End(); }
    }

    public class SustainedAction
    {
        public Character Player;
        public Character Target;

        public string Name;
        public int LeftTime;

        public SustainedAction(Character player, Character target, string name, int leftTime = 5)
        {
            Player = player;
            Target = target;
            Name = name;
            LeftTime = leftTime;

            Player.ActionsInParticiption.Add(this);
            Target.ActionsInParticiption.Add(this);
        }

        public void End()
        {
            // Check End Conditions...

            Player.ActionsInParticiption.Remove(this);
            Target.ActionsInParticiption.Remove(this);
            Player = null;
            Target = null;

            // maybe GC will remove it
        }

        public void Update(int time)
        {
            // playing action....

            // check left time
            LeftTime -= time;
            if (LeftTime < 0) End();
        }
    }

    public class Talk : SustainedAction
    {
        // The distinction between Player and Target is not important...
        public Talk(Character player, Character target) 
                        : base(player, target, "Talk", 10) { }
    }

    public class Lecture : SustainedAction
    {
        // Player is lecturer, Targets are student
        public Lecture(Character player, Character target) : base(player, target, "Lecture", 90) { }
    }

The problem is that mutual reference exists between SustainedAction and Character.
I don't think this is a good design, but I haven't found a way to improve while maintaining performance.
The issue is as follows :

maybe ShowActionList() is called frequently. This is why each Character remembers the list of Actions. without it, Character have to constantly query for find Action in participation.

Action is generated by Player, but Target and other characters also end it.

I didn't write it to simplify the pseudocode, but Player and Target can be multiple.


I would like to design this without mutual reference if possible. Any ideas would be appreciated.
*I'm not familiar with English, and this is machine translation. If you have any sentences you don't understand, please let me know in the comments.

it's not neccessarily a bad thing when two types references each other. Think of a Father knowing his Children, each knowing his Father.

I would use interfaces like ICharacter to have some decoupling and offer more flexibility for the future, take advantage on dependency injection and increase testability.

If the types are not allowed to reference each other, then you need an outside entity to reference both (and store the relations accordingly). Which you explicitly state you do not want for performance reasons.

I don't think this is a good design Why do you think so? Expanding this statement would possibly shed some light on what your requirements/expectations are.

IMO SustainedAction knows too much about Character. In particular it shouldn't add/remove instances of itself to/from ActionsInParticiption. As an idea to consider: SustainedAction has only a Target and no Player property. A Character (the player) has multiple SustainedActions and is responsible for adding to and removing from that list. Also if you ask your question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and add some more details you will likely get much better answers than here.

With your comments, I could see design that two types references each other is often used. I'll keep the questions for better ideas, but I'm working with this design .
Thank you all!
